# 404 Not Found when trying to access Flask-Admin on uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-admin

i'm a newbie in web programming, so i'm expecting to be missing a super simple thing in my configuration, hoping you can help me! (Also forgive my english - heh)

So here's the thing:
I'm on my little app on Flask, and everything works. In particular i'm messing around with Flask-Admin:

**123.45.67.8:8080/admin/**

returns my working admin panel... As soon as i switch from the built in server to nginx/uWSGI the url

**www.mywebsite.com/admin/**

gives me a 404...but only for the Flask-Admin part, everything else works perfectly!

i start uWSGI with the following command uwsgi --ini /path/to/myweb_uwsgi.ini

**myweb_uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/myweb

#python module to import
app = myweb
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/myweb/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

and this is my nginx .conf file

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/myweb/myweb_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something in uWSGI ini file, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm having a similar problem, but with mod_wsgi. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585050/flask-admin-pages-inaccessible-in-production

Comment: Had no luck sadly, i'll comment your question since i can't upvote questions yet, hopefully it will give it more visibility...
Edit: nevermind, commenting requires more reputation than upvoting does :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the app isn't initialized. Try moving the admin.Admin() initialization block away from the main function as well as adding the views. This is silly but not in the docs.