# Flask-Admin pages inaccessible in production

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi, flask-admin

I am trying to deploy my Flask app using Apache and mod_wsgi on an Ubuntu server.

It seems to work fine for restful requests that I have implemented, but I can't access my Flask-Admin pages (which I can access in development).

Here is the structure of my app (simplified for the purpose of this question) :

```
- MyApp/
    - main.py
    - myapp/
        - __init__.py
        - Views.py
        - files/
    - wsgi/
        myapp.wsgi
```

When in development, I simply run by using python main.py and everything works fine.

Here is the wsgi file :

```
import sys
import os

##Virtualenv Settings
activate_this = '/var/www/code/MyApp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

##Replace the standard out
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

##Add this file path to sys.path in order to import settings
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '../..'))

##Add this file path to sys.path in order to import app
sys.path.append('/var/www/code/MyApp/')

from myapp import app as application
```

Here is the configuration file for Apache, I'm using Apache 2.2 :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /var/www/code/MyApp/wsgi/myapp.wsgi
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/code/MyApp/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/code/MyApp/ssl.key
        SSLVerifyClient None
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

        <Directory /var/www/code/MyApp/wsgi>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is how I instantiate the Flask app in my __ *init* __.py :

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='files')
```

Here is how I create the Admin interface in my main.py :

```
# Create admin
admin = admin.Admin(app, 'App Administration')
```

I also have a link to the admin page in my Views.py :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Go to admin page</a>'
```

When in development, I can access the admin interface at mysite.com/admin/ .

In production, I have my app at mysite.com/myapp/ and I can't access the admin interface, which I expected to be at mysite.com/myapp/admin/ .

I think there's a problem with the way I instantiate flask-admin. I kept the default "admin/" url but maybe I need to declare a specific url when in production ?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT :**

I checked the Apache error log but I don't get any error.

Comment: Not related, but the line 'sys.stdout = sys.stderr' is not required unless you are using an even more ancient version of mod_wsgi than the Linux distributions use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update your route with "myapp"? Looks like you need to update your route for production. May even be able to drop the '/' on production. Try it.

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/myapp/')
def index():
```